# Getting out of nested if statement in php?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this code:

```
if (condition){  //number1
    if (condition){  //number2
        action
    }
}
else{
    action
}
```

Now if the nested if statement, number 2, turns out to be false is if possible to 'redirect' the program to the outside else statement rather than creating a nested else statement like so?

```
if (condition){  //number1
    if (condition){  //number2
        action
    }
    else {
        action;
    }
}
else {
    action
}
```

Edit: Here is my actual code:

```
if ($s == 5){  //which award is won
    $id_raw = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_ID FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."award".$award." WHERE user_ID='".$p_uid."'"); //check to see if user has already won this award
    if($id_raw==''){ // if he/she didnt make entry saying they did
        $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO ".$wpdb->prefix."award1 (user_ID, isTold) VALUES(".$p_uid.", 'false') ") or die(mysql_error());
        wp_delete_post( $pid, true );
    }
}
else{ 
    cp_points('voteitup_user_up', $uid, get_option('cp_module_voteitup_user_up'), $pid);
    cp_points('voteitup_author_up', $p_uid, get_option('cp_module_voteitup_author_up'), serialize(array($pid,$uid)));
}
```

Comment: `if (condition1 && !condition2) { that action; } else { other action; }`? `goto` is supported in `>= 5.3.0`, but is generally discouraged as well.

Comment: You do that by structuring your conditions more logically. For that we'd need know what the actual conditions are though. At least make the example clearer by naming the conditions `condition1` and `condition2` and the actions `action1` and so on.

Comment: @JaredFarrish- That would work but i have multiple nested if statements

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough information to answer your question. I suspect you're used to labels and `goto`s from another language, but @deceze is right, your approach is potentially sloppy and we need to see your actual code, not pseudocode.

Comment: @deceze: ive added my actual code.

Comment: the code is to check if a user has won an award or not, i am using wordpress to create the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing what you actually want to do here, since your `id_raw = ''` is a nonsense condition and the question is unclear:

```
$insert = $id == 5 && !$wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_ID FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."award".$award." WHERE user_ID='".$p_uid."'");
if ($insert) {
    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO ".$wpdb->prefix."award1 (user_ID, isTold) VALUES(".$p_uid.", 'false') ") or die(mysql_error());
    wp_delete_post( $pid, true );
} else {
    cp_points('voteitup_user_up', $uid, get_option('cp_module_voteitup_user_up'), $pid);
    cp_points('voteitup_author_up', $p_uid, get_option('cp_module_voteitup_author_up'), serialize(array($pid,$uid)));
}
```

Hope this gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Why not combine your first two if statements? Do you need to do other things in there?

```
if (condition1 && condition2) {
    action
}
else {
    action
}
```